# Product Attribute for saving Key-Value Pairs

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

We have a requirement to store values in Product Attributes in Key-Value pairs.
I am still searching for the solution, need assistance reagrding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

To store values in Product Attributes in Key-Value pairs

Follow this steps.

Create a new product attribute of type "Text" or "Textarea" in the Magento Admin panel. You can do this by navigating to **Stores -> Attributes -> Product** and clicking on the "Add New Attribute" button.

Fill in the necessary details for the attribute, such as the attribute code, label, input type, and other settings. Choose either "Text" or "Textarea" as the input type, depending on your requirements.

After saving the attribute, you can programmatically set and retrieve the key-value pairs using the attribute's code

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

// Inject the necessary dependencies in your class constructor
protected $productRepository;

public function __construct(
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

// Set the key-value pairs for a product attribute
public function setKeyValuePairs($productId, $keyValuePairs)
{
    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
    $product->setData('your_attribute_code', json_encode($keyValuePairs));
    $this->productRepository->save($product);
}
```

Retrieve the attribute value for a specific product:

```
 use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

// Inject the necessary dependencies in your class constructor
protected $productRepository;

public function __construct(
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

// Get the key-value pairs for a product attribute
public function getKeyValuePairs($productId)
{
    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
    $attributeValue = $product->getData('your_attribute_code');
    return json_decode($attributeValue, true);
}
```

In the above code, replace 'your_attribute_code'

The key-value pairs are encoded and decoded using JSON in this example, but you can use any other serialization method of your choice.

```
Hope this is useful to you
```